Playwright VSCode Plugin - Syntax Error: Unexpected Token
While using the Playwright plugin to write a test I encountered a problem that I'm not sure if it is directly tied to the plugin or the code editor and I hope you can tell me. To be honest this also happened a few weeks ago but it was fixed on its own by the morning. This time however it doesn't seem to go away. This is what happened:
I was writing my test but I suddenly needed a specific locator from my page so I ran one of my short tests with the option Show browser selected. Then the test itself took a long time to run, which has never happened before, so I clicked on the Stop square in the Playwright plugin. That however didn't stop it from 'running' (in quotes because the plugin showed the test as running but nothing was actively happening).
Then I tried using the Clear all test button from the Test Results terminal and reloading the window. That stopped the test from running but then my actual problem began.
In the Test Explorer I can see all of my test files but when I try expanding them none of the tests inside them show. Then when I went and looked through my tests I noticed a short red underline at the end of each file. When I hover over it I get this error message:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (380:0)

[0m [90m 378 |[39m }
 [90m 379 |[39m
[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 380 |[39m }
 [90m     |[39m [31m[1m^[22m[39m
 [90m 381 |[39m[0mplaywright

And I get the same message when I tried running the tests from the CLI.
I tried fully closing and opening VSCode again, updating to the newest version of Playwright, then tried disabling the plugin, then uninstalling it (here I noticed that the red underlines disappeared but then appeared again when I installed Playwright again).

Ok, I just checked all of my files again and noticed an extra  } at the end of the file and when I deleted it the problem was fixed. However the mystery is that I had not touched that file for days and I know it wasn't there before and the last time the same plugin problem happened there were no extra curly braces to delete.
